# Display percentage value of progress bar during AJAX upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, progress-bar

I can't seem to display my current upload value on my progress bar. I know how to do it, if the progress bar has stopped, but it won't work if I want it to update all the time.

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentage = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        $('div.progress-bar').css('width', percentage + '%');
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="progress progress-striped active hide">
    <div style="width: 0%" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active">
        <script>
            $("div.progress-bar").text($("div.progress-bar").width() + "%" );
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The progress bar itself runs fine. This code just outputs "0%" all the time, as the initial width()-value is 0. I want it to increase along with the progress bar dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you know that you have to update the width in the onprogress handler, but you don't know you have to also update the text in the handler. Why? Do you think that the script tag will dynamically bind the width to the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to also set the `text()` of the progress bar too:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentage = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        $('div.progress-bar').css('width', percentage + '%').text(percentage + '%');
    }
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the quick answer!